# Weird spiky bug found in northern Spain

Tags: species-identification, entomology

Does anyone know what this bug is? We're located in the north of Spain. Around 5mm long with spikes in its back.

First image is belly up, second one the bug is walking.

[image: belly up]
[image: walking]

Comment: The second photo looks almost *exactly* like the first, except blurry and without a shadow. Is that a mistake? Can you take a clearer photo of the dorsum (back) of the bug? Closer would be great! Thanks.

Comment: Sorry, they're not mine and the bug is no more. Supposedly the second one is the dorsum of the bug. I'm another site someone suggested it found be a cordyceps infected bug (didn't know the bug's species though :(

Comment: OK, I'll assume that because there are no legs visible adjacent the surface where there should be, this is just another picture of the upside down bug. The chances that there would be such a symmetrical multiple cordyceps infection are remote, to say the least.

Comment: Oh, then back to square one  it's a shame there aren't better pictures.